# InvalidAccessError Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer

Tengo el siguiente *ajax*, para la creación de una tarjeta de crédito, el script funciona perfectamente en Chrome, pero en IE no lo hace, me lanza un error `InvalidAccessError`, el sitio está sobre HTTPS.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
$('.js-payment-form').on('submit', function () {
    $('.js-payment-form-btn').prop('disabled', true);

    var valid = false;
    var key = $(this).data('public-key');

    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).data('api-url'),
        method: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            primaryAccountNumber: $('#id_number').val(),
            expirationMonth: $('#id_expiration_month').val(),
            expirationYear: $('#id_expiration_year').val(),
            cvc: $('#id_cvv').val(),
            cardHolderName: $(this).data('user-name').substring(0, 25)
        }),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        cache: false,
        username: key,
        headers: {'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa(key + ':')}
    }).done(function(response) {
        $('#id_token').val(response.token);
        valid = true;
    }).fail(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert('Tarjeta no valida, por favor intenta con una diferente.');
        $('.js-payment-form-btn').removeAttr('disabled');
    });

    return valid;
});
```

¿Alguien tiene idea de por qué pasa esto?

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que IE no interpreta bien tu código, Si usas la version menor a 8.0 de IE no te funcionará `JSON.stringify()`?
Esta parte parece no estar funcionando:

```
JSON.stringify({
            primaryAccountNumber: $('#id_number').val(),
            expirationMonth: $('#id_expiration_month').val(),
            expirationYear: $('#id_expiration_year').val(),
            cvc: $('#id_cvv').val(),
            cardHolderName: $(this).data('user-name').substring(0, 25)
```

Consulta la siguiente liga para que entiendas mas de JSON.stringify y ve si has omitido algo que no has publicado en la pregunta.

[Lo que se necesita saber de JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify)